# Configure IIS for enabling directory browsing without Kestrel to hijack route

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a simple asp.net core application on my computer hosted on my IIS.
Let say I have a site on my computer like this:

https://computername/application

I have a virutual directory called logs.

So for https://computername/application/logs I want to be able to directory browse, but when I go to /logs the app return 404, and I think that is because Kestrel doesn't find a route to /logs.

**How can I make the IIS handle the /logs instead of Kestrel?**

I think it should be possible to handle this in web.config but I have no idea how.

the directory browsing setting is enabled in IIS for the site so that's not the problem.

I hope you understand my problem, otherwise I can gladly elaborate.
Thanks!

Comment: does it work if you create a web.config in your virtual directory that removes the `aspNetCore` handler?

Comment: It does @MartinUllrich! Will update answer later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with adding a web.config at the virtual folder.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
           <remove name="aspNetCore" />
        </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```